# How to detect the active Controller Manager and Scheduler in a Kubernetes HA Master setup?

Tags: kubernetes, high-availability

I've set a **kubernetes** cluster with master in **high availability**: 3 etcd nodes, 3 apiservers, 3 controller managers and 3 schedulers. There is a load balancer in front of the api servers. I see apiservers running as **Active-Active** while Controller Manager and Scheduler are working as **Active/Standby**. Does anyone know how to detect the active Controller Manager and Scheduler in a HA Master setup?

All the K8s infra components are managed by systemd not by dockerd.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my case, retrieving the endpoints yaml and looking in the "holderIdentity" field of the "...kubernetes.io/leader" annotation.

Comment: Thanks! Here in my case: `kubectl -n kube-system get ep kube-scheduler -o yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Endpoints
metadata:
  annotations:
    control-plane.alpha.kubernetes.io/leader: '{"holderIdentity":"kubem02","leaseDurationSeconds":15,"acquireTime":"2017-08-25T08:11:24Z","renewTime":"2017-08-25T08:11:48Z","leaderTransitions":6}'
  creationTimestamp: 2017-08-22T10:52:02Z
  name: kube-scheduler
  namespace: kube-system
  resourceVersion: "284677"
  selfLink: /api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/endpoints/kube-scheduler
  uid: ee232b16-8727-11e7-81f6-000c29f8a512
`

Answer (score 1):

I use below commands to find out the leader

```
kubectl proxy --port=8000

curl 127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/endpoints/kube-controller-manager | grep leader

curl 127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/endpoints/kube-scheduler | grep leader
```